# Angular 4 routerLinkActive not adding class active

Tags: angular, angular2-router, routerlinkactive

I want to style the css and add class when a link is active using **routerLinkActive**. I have tried in bootstrap and it works, but then when I got the custom CSS from the front end developer, it won't add the class that states that it is active, even when the route url is match the **routeLink**.

I am a bit frustated and have no idea what is wrong. I expect it will add class *menu-active* in the anchor when the route is active.

here's my code:

***sidebar.component.html***

```
<li class="menu-parent">
  <a class="menu-item" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="menu-active">
    <i class="ti ti-anchor"></i>
    <span class="menu-text">Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I have tested like the code below, referenced from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576766/angular-2-routerlinkactive). I expect the *i* showed because the routerlink is active, but it doesn't, even when I am in the *http://localhost:4200/dashboard*.

```
<li class="menu-parent">
  <a class="menu-item" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
    <i class="ti ti-anchor" *ngIf="rla.isActive"></i>
    <span class="menu-text">Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Hope someone could clear my frustration. Thank you.

**Update:**

The class is not even added when I inspect the element. Here's the screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: Does the link work as expected? Have you checked in dev tools if the class gets applied to the anchor element?

Comment: @Hinrich yes the link has worked when I click on it. The class is not applied when I inspect the element. I have added the screenshot in my question update.

Comment: Looks good to me so far. Can you please also show the routing configuration?

Comment: The code you provided looks fine. Could you try to reproduce the problem on a playground like codepen or plunkr?

Comment: @hinrich I have found the solution. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. My routerLinkActive broke because I use ***ngIf** in my **component selector**. I supposed to make the navbar shown if the user had logged in, and the *navbar* was also a *wrapper* for my content. So I used *ngIf to hide the navbar if the user is not logged in. And that was where my problem start. My navbar contains sidebar and topbar, which I have merged to avoid adding *ngIf in the component selector again.

***src/app/app.component.html***

```
<app-navbar *ngIf="isLoggedIn; else loginpage"></app-navbar>

<ng-template #loginpage>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

the *isLoggedIn* in my code contains Boolean, whether the user has logged in or not.

***The solution***: every route will load the navbar, but I put the ***ngIf="isLoggedIn"** within the navbar divs, so if the user is not logged in, it won't show the sidebar and show the content only instead.

***src/app/app.component.html***

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

***src/app/navbar/navbar.component.html***

```
<div id="wrapper" [ngClass]="menu" *ngIf="isLoggedIn; else loginpage">
   <div class="side-menu" id="sidebar-wrapper" >
    // the sidebar HTML
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper-body">
       <div class="top-menu" >
        // the topbar HTML
       </div>

       <div class="content-wrapper">
          <div class="row main-content">
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loginpage>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

I never thought that putting *ngIf in the component selector will waste 2-3 days of my app development. I never find in the documentation that structural directives cannot be added in component selector. Any of you find that in the documentation? Thank you for all your help guys!

Comment: *ngIf can be used in component selectors. The problem was that you were referencing  "isLoggedIn" from within the AppComponent, but that variable was not in AppComponent

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the Component cannot reference the `.menu-active` class.

Is the class declared in **sidebar.component.css** or per inline css in **sidebar.component.ts** ?

Comment: It seems like the class is never assigned to the element, so css should not be the actual problem.

Comment: @SplitterAlex the class is declared in sidebar.component.css